# How do I make parts of a texture transparent

Tags: texturing

I'm making a Minecraft animation, but all the grass in my scene looks like this:[image]

I've tried to make the black parts transparent using what I found on Youtube, but it's not working. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Here is the Blend file:
[image]

Comment: in Eevee you need to go into your Material panel and under Settings > Blend Mode, choose Alpha Blend, maybe it's your problem here?

Comment: In your material properties, scroll down untill where it says "Blend Mode" and change it away from _opaque_ (Pick either alpha-clip, alpha-blend, or alpha-hashed - I prefer blend)

Comment: @moonboots - Great minds, eh?

Comment: I've tried changing the blend mode, but it creates a weird effect on it and it doesn't looks the way I want it to

Comment: Can you describe (or post an image of) the "weird effect"? Also, in the shading tab, is your image connected to both the _basecolor_ and the _alpha_ of the Principled BSDF?

Comment: @ Christopher Bennett eh eh sorry I've been several seconds faster  ;)

Comment: @ Nico J, please pack your image and share one of your objects so that we can check: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots Here's the file: https://pasteall.org/blend/99f2e2255d3440c399a2c924aff47d7f

Comment: The images have not been packed. Go to *File* -> *External Data* -> *Automatically Pack Into .blend* Also, please use https://blend-exchange.com/ for this site, and paste your .blend into your main question.

Comment: I just fixed it. Thank you all for helping and the answers did help me fix it. Thanks!

Comment: it seems to work fine, for your alpha image texture, make sure you set it to Closest and not Linear: https://zupimages.net/up/21/35/cpk6.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. The problem was that the Alpha texture was not set to Closest. Thanks for helping.